# ¿Cómo guardo un valor de una base de datos en una variable en typescript?

Tags: mysql, typescript, async-await

Necesito hacer un programa el cual busque dentro de una base de datos un dato y lo guarde en una variable para usarlo después en otras partes del código

tengo un esto

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //datos de conexión
});

const userRFC: string = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var boolSwiDB: boolean = false; 

connection.query('SELECT value FROM tabla WHERE rfc= ?', [userRFC], (error, results, fields) => {
    if(error){
        console.error('Error al realizar la consulta', error);
    }else {
        boolSwiDB= true;
    }
});
```

El problema es que posteriormente al usar boolSwiDB más adelante en el código su valor sigue siendo 'False' aunque, intente crear una función usando async silimar a esto

```
async function boolChange(findRFC: string): Promise<boolean>{
    connection.query('SELECT perc_ded02 FROM cheque_cpto WHERE rfc= ?', [userRFC], (error, results, fields) => {
        if(error){
            console.error('Error al realizar la consulta', error);
            return false;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Pero esto me produce el error ts(2355) que básicamente dice que me hace falta un return. Tambien probe devolver toda la conexión de modo:

```
async function boolChange(findRFC: string): Promise<boolean>{
    return connection.query('SELECT perc_ded02 FROM cheque_cpto WHERE rfc= ?', [userRFC], (error, results, fields) => {
        if(error){
            false;
        }else {
            true;
        }
    });
}
```

Si necesitan mas datos estaré feliz de compartirlos